# Maximum number of times an IF function can be nested

Tags: excel, excel-formula, nested

I am getting ready to create an abnormally long `IF` function with other `IF` functions nested in it and before I start I wanted to see if anyone knew if there was a limit to how many nested functions you can have.

This site (http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/if_nested.php) says that the max is 7 times but I have done more than 7...

Comment: Excel circa 2003 had a nesting limit of 7 but there were ways to get around that. Excel 2007-2013 has a limit of 64 but there is almost always a better way to construct a formula if you need anything remotely close to that. See [Excel specifications and limits](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3). "Nested levels of functions - 64"

Comment: Perfect, I shouldn't need anything close to 64. But I will need at least 40

Comment: Still too many. Post some sample data together with the expected results and what you have tried so far and a better solution should present itself.

Comment: Okay I will post a picture in a new question in a few min

Comment: Uh, yeah. I usually don't bother with pictures of sample data. See [Why Not Images of Code and Sample Data](http://tinyurl.com/kdxb7le).

Comment: ah good point, I'll figure out a way to properly structure it in a question and ask the question. Thanks for the tip

Comment: You can update this question with your new data. No need to ask a new question and leave this as an open one. Better to edit this one and let it be resolved.

Comment: Depending on what you're actually trying to do, I have found that most people that people a very big nested `IF` equation should actually restructure their equation to use the `CHOOSE` function instead.  http://chandoo.org/wp/2014/07/16/introduction-to-choose-function/

Comment: The choose function is very handy in other instances. The problem with this data set is that the IF function is letting me categorize a given date into a particular fiscal year month. Using the excel months won't work because a fiscal year month is different that a calendar year month. I think I might have thought of a solution to my limit of 64 nested IFs and I will post my answer if it works out.

Comment: Adjust your dates within the formula with the [EDATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/edate-function-1586b161-4361-4a6d-939b-9d96eae962a8) using a positive or negative *months* parameter to push the date forward or backward into the appropriate fiscal year.

Comment: Create a static table and then perform VLOOKUP with your data.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on which version of Excel you are using.  Prior to 2007 the limit was 7, but from 2007 onward it is 64.  You can see this if you try to type the following formula:

```
=IF(L20=1,1,IF(L20=2,2,IF(L20=3,3,IF(L20=4,4,IF(L20=5,5,IF(L20=6,6,IF(L20=7,7,IF(L20=8,8,IF(L20=1,1,IF(L20=2,2,IF(L20=3,3,IF(L20=4,4,IF(L20=5,5,IF(L20=6,6,IF(L20=7,7,IF(L20=8,8,IF(L20=1,1,IF(L20=2,2,IF(L20=3,3,IF(L20=4,4,IF(L20=5,5,IF(L20=6,6,IF(L20=7,7,IF(L20=8,8,IF(L20=1,1,IF(L20=2,2,IF(L20=3,3,IF(L20=4,4,IF(L20=5,5,IF(L20=6,6,IF(L20=7,7,IF(L20=8,8,IF(L20=1,1,IF(L20=2,2,IF(L20=3,3,IF(L20=4,4,IF(L20=5,5,IF(L20=6,6,IF(L20=7,7,IF(L20=8,8,IF(L20=1,1,IF(L20=2,2,IF(L20=3,3,IF(L20=4,4,IF(L20=5,5,IF(L20=6,6,IF(L20=7,7,IF(L20=8,8,IF(L20=1,1,IF(L20=2,2,IF(L20=3,3,IF(L20=4,4,IF(L20=5,5,IF(L20=6,6,IF(L20=7,7,IF(L20=8,8,IF(L20=1,1,IF(L20=2,2,IF(L20=3,3,IF(L20=4,4,IF(L20=5,5,IF(L20=6,6,IF(L20=7,7,IF(L20=8,8,IF(L20=1,1,IF(L20=2,2,IF(L20=3,3,IF(L20=4,4,IF(L20=5,5,IF(L20=6,6,IF(L20=7,7,IF(L20=8,8,0))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))
```

There are over 64 levels of nesting here, and Excel will display a message box saying "The specified formula cannot be entered because it uses more than 64 levels of nesting".

Answer (score 0):

THAT,
This very question was bothering me for some time, so, just for fun, I went after it and here's a result (When Microsoft says so, it has to work). I made a few changes in the code posted by iliketocode.

```
=IF(L20=1,1,IF(L20=2,2,IF(L20=3,3,IF(L20=4,4,IF(L20=5,5,IF(L20=6,6,IF(L20=7,7,IF(L20=8,8,IF(L20=9,9,IF(L20=10,10,IF(L20=11,11,IF(L20=12,12,IF(L20=13,13,IF(L20=14,14,IF(L20=15,15,IF(L20=16,16,IF(L20=17,17,IF(L20=18,18,IF(L20=19,19,IF(L20=20,20,IF(L20=21,21,IF(L20=22,22,IF(L20=23,23,IF(L20=24,24,IF(L20=25,25,IF(L20=26,26,IF(L20=27,27,IF(L20=28,28,IF(L20=29,29,IF(L20=30,30,IF(L20=31,31,IF(L20=32,32,IF(L20=33,33,IF(L20=34,34,IF(L20=35,35,IF(L20=36,36,IF(L20=37,37,IF(L20=38,38,IF(L20=39,39,IF(L20=40,40,IF(L20=41,41,IF(L20=42,42,IF(L20=43,43,IF(L20=44,44,IF(L20=45,45,IF(L20=46,46,IF(L20=47,47,IF(L20=48,48,IF(L20=49,49,IF(L20=50,50,IF(L20=51,51,IF(L20=52,52,IF(L20=53,53,IF(L20=54,54,IF(L20=55,55,IF(L20=56,56,IF(L20=57,57,IF(L20=58,58,IF(L20=59,59,IF(L20=60,60,IF(L20=61,61,IF(L20=62,62,IF(L20=63,63,IF(L20=64,64,IF(L20=65,65,)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))
```